# force windows to have case sensitive for development

Tags: javascript, linux, windows, reactjs

Today I spent hours to figure out what's wrong in my production environment (linux) when my project in my local (windows) is fine. I found this culprit:

```
import 'something' from '../App/myComponent'
```

above code is running fine although my App folder is in lower case, during my development I didn't see any error, but in my product, stuffs are breaking.

How to force windows to have `strict mode`?

Comment: faced the same problem once, not with React but with Java, windows development can sometimes be very painful. Shifted to linux after that :)

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Webpack, use [`CaseSensitivePathsPlugin`](https://github.com/Urthen/case-sensitive-paths-webpack-plugin)  to enforce that the path of imported modules matches the case of the path on disk.

Answer (score 0):

While technically NTFS is case-sensitive, the insensitivity is too deep in the Win32 subsystem. I’m afraid it’s impossible to switch.

My advice is, use [WSL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Subsystem_for_Linux) instead. That thing is targeted towards developers, and these lxss.sys / lxcore.sys drivers will emulate Linux environment just fine, including case sensitive file system (since Win10 anniversary update).